# How to prevent website blinks to white theme when dark theme enabled

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a problem with my website, when I refrech a web page and the dark theme enabled, it blinks to white for less than one sec and back to dark
so how to fix that problem

my js code,

```
/*==================== DARK LIGHT THEME ====================*/ 
const themeButton = document.getElementById('theme-button')
const darkTheme = 'dark-theme'
const iconTheme = 'bx-sun'

// Previously selected topic (if user selected)
const selectedTheme = localStorage.getItem('selected-theme')
const selectedIcon = localStorage.getItem('selected-icon')

// We obtain the current theme that the interface has by validating the dark-theme class
const getCurrentTheme = () => document.body.classList.contains(darkTheme) ? 'dark' : 'light'
const getCurrentIcon = () => themeButton.classList.contains(iconTheme) ? 'bx-moon' : 'bx-sun'

// We validate if the user previously chose a topic
if (selectedTheme) {
  // If the validation is fulfilled, we ask what the issue was to know if we activated or deactivated the dark
  document.body.classList[selectedTheme === 'dark' ? 'add' : 'remove'](darkTheme)
  themeButton.classList[selectedIcon === 'bx-moon' ? 'add' : 'remove'](iconTheme)
}

// Activate / deactivate the theme manually with the button
themeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Add or remove the dark / icon theme
    document.body.classList.toggle(darkTheme)
    themeButton.classList.toggle(iconTheme)
    // We save the theme and the current icon that the user chose
    localStorage.setItem('selected-theme', getCurrentTheme())
    localStorage.setItem('selected-icon', getCurrentIcon())
})

/*==================== SCROLL REVEAL ANIMATION ====================*/
const sr = ScrollReveal({
    origin: 'top',
    distance: '30px',
    duration: 1000,
    reset: true
});

sr.reveal(` .home__data, .home__img,
            .about__data, .about__img,
            .services__content, .menu__content,
            .app__data, .app__img,
            .contact__data, .contact__button,
            .footer__content`, {
    interval: 200
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, web browsers will first load your HTML file, then it will load your CSS file, and only after that, it will load your JavaScript file.

By default, HTML web pages are blank, they're white, so until your JavaScript file is rendered to the DOM, you'll see the white background first.